# Azure Web Application Monitoring Alert doesn't fire

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have configured an Azure Web Application Monitoring rule such that if there are more than 30 requests over a five minute period, then an alert should fire which should both send me an email and trigger a webhook.

Problem is, the alert doesn't fire even when the parameters for the alert are clearly satisfied. I took a screenshot of the traffic graph after I made over 30 requests to the server within a five-minute window. I've also included the specific configuration menus for this alert.

How can I make this alert fire?

[image: Screenshot of the server requests and the specified alert]

[image: alert configuration]

Comment: My guess here is that if there was a flat line @ more than 30 for a period of 5 mins - meaning if you had requests greater than 30 for a continuous period of of 5 mins, your alert would work

Answer (score 1):

I checked one of my alerts a similar one that was set to a threshold of 5 mins for response time, I find that these alerts were fired , if my response time for a give requests exceed a certain time (12MS) and that if it had happened for a period of 5 minutes, email needs to be sent.  I have attached a snapshot as to when this happened to help understand what this might be - so in your case , `to measure if the requests were greater than 30 at say 12:00PM - until 12:05 PM - (ie) for a period of 5 mins, your alert would fire` - if it did not, then you may need to check something else. [image]

So my guess here is that if there was a flat line @ more than 30 for a period of 5 mins - meaning if you had requests greater than 30 for a continuous period of of 5 mins, your alert would and should work.