# Active documentDb alert rule is not reacting

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have created some different alert rules for my Azure documentDb. The problem is that after creating them they look as if they are up and running. Except nothing happens when I clearly see that the rule is achieved. Is there something that I miss creating the rule?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at this similar [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235714/azure-web-application-monitoring-alert-doesnt-fire) about alert rules?

Comment: @Bruce-MSFT Yes, but they don't seem to solve it. The only answer say that it should work, except that it doesn't. So I wanted to check if someone knew more now than 5 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I have found the answer. It seems that apparently the count have to be consistent over the limit for the whole duration of the period for the alert to go of.

I'll have to keep looking for a solution that fits my needs.